# Private RESTful web service for Android/iOS app and website. Yay or nay?

Tags: android, ios, rest

The startup I work for is making an Android/iOS app and a website offering a subset of the features of the app. My idea is to make a RESTful backend service which can then be consumed by all three clients. The backend must handle following things

- User login/registration and authentication.
- Image upload/download for any user
- Some sort of location API to get all uploads/downloads in particular area.

My question is, is it a good idea to make a RESTful web service for this or is there some better solution that I am failing to take into account? The API will only be used by the three  clients I mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, having a platform independent RESTful service is by far the best practice here - some minor changes may need to be made available to the different platforms through different endpoints but all in all it should be a single service.

Answer (score 1):

I think using RESTful web service is good idea. If you want make app both for android and IOS then WS is best to use. Because making one WS can be used for multiple client. Though you want to use it for some confidential data, Use some security for it.